# My code is being compiled to absolute paths!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I'm having problems deploying my application to a production server (shared hosting). Everything works fine on my development machine but not on the server due to absolute paths, here's a stack trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'GLASGOW\IWPD_1479(fisharw)'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5009598
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +85
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +349
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +265
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +34

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +163
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +40
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +157
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +51
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +117
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +407
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext() +20
   Sharwe.Data.DataAccess.SharweEntities..ctor() in C:\Users\Kassem\Desktop\Sharwe\Sharwe.Data\DataAccess\SharweEntities.cs:14
   Sharwe.Data.DataAccess.EfDatabaseFactory.GetDbContext() in C:\Users\Kassem\Desktop\Sharwe\Sharwe.Data\DataAccess\EFDatabaseFactory.cs:14
   Sharwe.Data.DataAccess.GenericMethodsRepository..ctor(IDatabaseFactory dbFactory) in C:\Users\Kassem\Desktop\Sharwe\Sharwe.Data\DataAccess\GenericMethodsRepository.cs:21
   lambda_method(Closure , IArguments ) +80
   StructureMap.Construction.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateBuilder>b__0(IArguments args) +22
   StructureMap.Construction.InstanceBuilder.BuildInstance(IArguments args) +12
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, IInstanceBuilder builder) +88

[StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code:  207
Internal exception while creating Instance 'ac34765c-b076-4f77-be6e-eb4739ea2738' of PluginType Sharwe.Data.Abstract.IGenericMethodsRepository.  Check the inner exception for more details.]
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, IInstanceBuilder builder) +276
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +41
   StructureMap.Pipeline.SmartInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +43
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +45
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +36
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session) +103
   StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance) +49
   StructureMap.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() +22
   StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) +24
   StructureMap.Pipeline.DefaultInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +76
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +45
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +36
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get(String propertyName, BuildSession session) +73
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Arguments.Get(String propertyName) +64
   lambda_method(Closure , IArguments ) +35
   StructureMap.Construction.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateBuilder>b__0(IArguments args) +22
   StructureMap.Construction.InstanceBuilder.BuildInstance(IArguments args) +12
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, IInstanceBuilder builder) +98
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +41
   StructureMap.Pipeline.SmartInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +43
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +45
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +36
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session) +103
   StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance) +49
   StructureMap.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() +22
   StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) +24
   StructureMap.Pipeline.DefaultInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +76
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +45
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +36
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get(String propertyName, BuildSession session) +73
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Arguments.Get(String propertyName) +64
   lambda_method(Closure , IArguments ) +35
   StructureMap.Construction.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateBuilder>b__0(IArguments args) +22
   StructureMap.Construction.InstanceBuilder.BuildInstance(IArguments args) +12
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, IInstanceBuilder builder) +98
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +41
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +45
   StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) +36
   StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session) +103
   StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance) +49
   StructureMap.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() +22
   StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) +24
   StructureMap.Container.GetInstance(Type pluginType) +67
   Sharwe.MVC.Services.StructureMapDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) in C:\Users\Kassem\Desktop\Sharwe\Sharwe\Services\StructureMapDependencyResolver.cs:24
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +51

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Sharwe.MVC.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +196
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +13
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8841400
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

So as you can see, there are several places where it says `C:\Users\Kassem\Desktop\Sharwe\Sharwe\` which is where the project is located on my local machine. I do not understand why the code compiled this way, shouldn't it use relative paths automatically?

Note: My solution is divided into 3 projects, one of them is an ASP.NET MVC3 application which references the other projects (code libraries). In order to compile the whole project I right clicked on the MVC3 project and chose Build, and from there I deployed to a local directory then uploaded the files to the server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just debug information embedded in the pdb file.... That's all. It's used when debugging to find the original source code.

Comment: I got this error when trying to view the site online. Check it out: www.fisharwe.com , if that's not the problem, then what could be causing this issue? Is it something in my code or something from the server environment?

Comment: In your case above it is a login error to SQL server. Check the account name and password and database server and database permissions.

Comment: I double checked the connection string and all of the above (except database permissions). But I can access the database using SQL Management Studio using the username and password that I'm using in the connection string, does that tell me anything?

Comment: Apparently you were right. It was actually something with the connection string and some permission issue. Thank you :)